# Building Array in order of income objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm getting an XML and parsing it, saving it to array, the problems is that I get objects in this order:

```
temp1.ID = 15
temp1.name = "Dan"
temp1.phone = "32332"

temp2.ID = 12
temp2.name = "Test"
temp2.phone = 53463

temp3.ID = 2
temp3.name = "Tom"
temp3.phone = 12443
.
.
.
.
```

`Object` -  its an objects that I get inside a loop while parsing `XML`

What I try is to save them in the same order I started to read them : `Array: [temp1,temp2,temp3]`

But The result of the next function is : `Array: [temp3,temp2,temp1]`

the function:

```
    this.mytempect = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) {
                var temp = {};
                temp.ID = parseXmlByTag(xml[i], "ID");
                temp.name = parseXmlByTag(xml[i], "name");
                temp.phone = parseXmlByTag(xml[i], "phone");

                  if (this.mytempect [temp .ID] == null) {
                    this.mytempect [temp .ID] = [];
                }
                this.mytempect [temp .ID].push(obj);
}
```

Before I save each object I check if I need to create for him a new Key or to add to existing one, in the end I get something like this:

I need to save the order in which I'm getting them so I'll save them in the order I entered them

Comment: you are using `temp.ID` as the index but if you don't want that order, you canna do it, captain™, and will need to find if it already exists using e.g. an _Object_ map id->index

Comment: What is `obj`? You don't define that anywhere.

Comment: you could use `reverse()`

Comment: @MindaugasVečkys it's only the example that has them in reverse order, from how it's described, the objects could be received with their _id_ in any order

Comment: Object it a temp object (in the question) that I get inside the loop...the point here that I getting object, I want to save all the objects with the same ID by the order I'm getting them from start

Comment: @PaulS. I am using temp.ID because I'm getting a lot of objects with similar ID what I want is to save an array with that will collapse those elements under any kind of key, what I thought about is to save it into array[ID] but its sorting it the wrongway

Comment: are you sure that the items in the original `xml` array are in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question here's what I think you should be doing. You seem to be confusing objects and arrays: `mytempect` needs to be an object if you want to store arrays against a key set by the `ID`.

Following your example, objects with the same key are assigned to the same array (identified by that key in the object) *in the order in which they are read*.

```
// create an object, not an array
this.mytempect = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var temp = {};
  temp.ID = arr[i].ID;
  temp.name = arr[i].name;
  temp.phone = arr[i].phone;

  // Don't check for null here because `this.mytempect[temp.ID]` might not exist
  if (!this.mytempect[temp.ID]) {
    this.mytempect[temp.ID] = [];
  }
  this.mytempect[temp.ID].push(temp);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qV22A/)

The demo produces an object with one object in an array under key `15`, two under `12` and one under `2`:

```
{
  "2": [
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "name": "Tom",
      "phone": 12443
    }
  ],
  "12": [
    {
      "ID": 12,
      "name": "Test",
      "phone": 53463
    },
    {
      "ID": 12,
      "name": "Test",
      "phone": 53462
    }
  ],
  "15": [
    {
      "ID": 15,
      "name": "Dan",
      "phone": "32332"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: you can't order the object in any way.

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to change anything essential. At least I don't see why this would produce a different order of the array items.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this

```
var mytempect = [],
    dict = {},
    i,
    tmp;
for (i = 0; i < xml.length; ++i) {
    tmp = {
        ID: parseXmlByTag(xml[i], "ID"),
        name: parseXmlByTag(xml[i], "name"),
        phone: parseXmlByTag(xml[i], "phone")
    };
    if (!(tmp.ID in dict)) {
        mytempect.push(dict[tmp.ID] = []);
    }
    dict[tmp.ID].push(tmp); // use fact Objects ByRef to add item
}
dict = null; // cleanup
```

The *Array* `mytempect` will now have indices `0`, `1`, `2`, etc containing *Arrays* of all *Objects* which have the same *ID*. With your sample data you will get

```
mytempect[0][0].ID === 15;
mytempect[1][0].ID === 12;
mytempect[2][0].ID === 2;
```